# How many 4 character "words" can be created with (A,B,C,D)

Tags: combinatorics

**How many 4  character "words" can be created with (A,B,C,D), if you can take how many you want of each character.**

**Correct answer**: 256

Okay so the words don't have to be "real" english words.
A B C D

A B C D

A B C D

A B C D

So those possible combinations 4*4 = 16

And 4! = 24

But 24 * 16 = 384 and not **256**

Anyone that knows a solution for this problem? :)

Comment: Your question is has ambiguity for me. Please edit it.

Comment: I think they mean that one word could be AAAA or AAAD for example

Comment: So, repeated character is allowed. $4^4$ is correct answer for repeated and $4!$ is for non-repeated character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So those possible combinations 4*4 = 16

What do you mean by *those*...?

If you have to create a four letter word by selecting letters from {A,B,C,D}, notice that you have:

- 4 possibilities for the first letter;
- 4 possibilities for the second letter;
- 4 possibilities for the third letter;
- 4 possibilities for the fourth letter.

This makes a total of $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 4^4 = 256$ words.

Comment: Thanks your solution makes sense : )

Comment: i got a follow up question how many of these 256 words got at least one "A". 


Correct answer: 175 But i dont get it

Comment: Easier: how many have *no* A at all?

Comment: 4*4*4 = 64 maybe?

Comment: No. Repeat the previous solution, but using no A's, so only using B, C and D.

Comment: Ok thanks will do

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 choices for the first letter. There are 4 choices for the second letter, 4 choices for the third, and 4 choices for the last. The total number of possible "words" is: $4^4 = 256$.

Comment: Cool thanks! :D